# Garbage Collection Disables Listview Source from loading Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, xamarin.forms, garbage-collection

Having an issue where my listview source objects are being garbage collected in my app. I have a tabbed page and the default content page has a working list view, and with almost identical code the second content page has another list view but the objects aren't displaying. Is there anyway to prevent them from being garbage collected?

Here is my code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MIApp.Classes;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MIApp
{
    public partial class VideosListPage : ContentPage
    {
        public VideosListPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected async override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            string url = "https://example.net/api/Videos/GetVideos";
            var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string res = "";
                using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                {
                    Task<string> result = content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    res = result.Result;
                    var VideosList = Videos.VideosItems.FromJson(res);
                    VideosListView.ItemsSource = VideosList;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Connection Error", "Please Connect to the internet and try again", "Ok");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I am Getting a JSON String from an API that converts entries in a database to a JSON array of objects. I then convert it to a list of objects when I declare VideosList var from a class in which the objects are constructed and deserialised here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace MIApp.Classes
{
    public class Videos
    {
        public partial class VideosItems
        {
            [JsonProperty("$id")]
            public long Id { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("intVideoID")]
            public string IntVideoId { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("strVideoTitle")]
            public string StrVideoTitle { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("strVideoURL")]
            public string StrVideoURL { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("strVideoPhotoUrl")]
            public string StrVideoPhotoUrl { get; set; }
        }

        public partial class VideosItems
        {
            public static List<VideosItems> FromJson(string json)
            {
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<VideosItems>>(json);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Just FYI, when debugging line by line, when I hover over var Videos List it expands and has the correct count of objects but the resource cannot be found because the objects have been garbage collected.

Thank,
Ryan

Answer (score 0):

Make the VideosList a global variable, it's scope is limited to

```
        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
        {
            Task<string> result = content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            res = result.Result;
            var VideosList = Videos.VideosItems.FromJson(res);
            VideosListView.ItemsSource = VideosList;
        }
```

this using block only, so once the compiler goes out of block the VideoList variable gets garbage collected. If you declare that on the class level, it will not happen.

Comment: Why is that necessary, why isn't assigning it to `VideosListView.ItemsSource` enough? Also, the variable doesn't get garbage collected, the variable goes out of scope, the object it refers to may be eligible for garbage collection if there are no more references to it, which is why I ask why assigning it to `VideosListView.ItemsSource` isn't enough to keep it alive.

Comment: I am not sure , but VideosListView.ItemsSource is a bindable property and might not be an actual object. What I mean to say is the type of ItemSource and VideoList are not of same type. So it's not like ItemSource would point to the memory location of the VideoList. There's a abstract relation between them, by which ItemSource is able to consume the data in VideoList but not exactly having the reference to the VideoList variable.

Comment: If it "consumes" these objects, does it convert them into something else? Because if so, why wouldn't you want to garbage collect the original?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Good point, but I think it's more of a runtime mapping than typecasting and saving the object reference. But again I am not sure, you might wanna check with the xamarin team to clarify. They only how how is it working internally.